# How to register service worker on other domain using sub-domain

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have domain like https://example.com and hosting service worker js and main js on it. I am trying to register service worker on other website like https://example2.com.
**Till now what I have tried:**
I had created sub-domain like https://example2.example.com and put both main js and service worker js in that folder and registering service worker on 'example2.com' using this sub-domain like https://example2.example.com/serviceworker.js and https://example2.example.com/main.js but it is giving me error like:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

**I have two questions from this conditions:**

> 1. Is it possible to register service worker hosted on different domain ?
> 2. If possible then why is it giving me this error and how to do it ?

I am using only javascript to avoid any dependency.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you fix it? I am also facing same issue. I also need to load service-worker file from another domain.

Comment: Answer provided by santab works for me. You can use pop window which will open in you first domain website and have url of second domain website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their is one tricky way to register service worker cross-domain and almost every website doing so is by this way. You can register it by using pop-up window.
**Steps:**

> 1.Create a new html page in your sub-domain directory and like https://example2.example.com/index.html
> 2.Add your main.js in this index.html page.
> 3.Now instead of loading main.js in https://example2.com open pop window with link https://example2.example.com/index.html

Once your service worker registered, their will be no domain dependency and you can do whatever you want to with this. In this way you can register service worker without redirecting.

Comment: Thanks, This did the trick. I am looking for solutions for all day.

Comment: when should we open popup window? allow or deny popup to user will not show before registering service worker.